# How to prevent mysqldump from splitting dumps into 1MB increments?

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly large MySQL table (11.5 million rows). In terms of data size, the table is ~2GB.

My `max_allowed_packet` is 64MB. I'm backing up the table using `mysqldump` by creating a batch of inserts (500,000 values each), because the resulting sql file produced using the mysqldump option `--skip-extended-insert` just takes too long to re-insert.

This is what I'm running (from a perl script):

```
`mysqldump -u root -pmypassword --no-data mydb mytable > mybackup.sql`

my $offset = 0;
while ($offset < $row_count) {
    `mysqldump -u root -p[mypassword] --opt --no-create-info --skip-add-drop-table --where="1 LIMIT $offset, 500000" mydb mytable >> mybackup.sql`
}
```

The resulting sql file is 900MB. Check out the following output of `grep -n '\-\- WHERE\:  1 LIMIT' mybackup.sql`:

```
80:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 0, 500000
158:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 500000, 500000
236:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 1000000, 500000
314:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 1500000, 500000
392:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 2000000, 500000
469:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 2500000, 500000
546:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 3000000, 500000
623:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 3500000, 500000
699:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 4000000, 500000
772:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 4500000, 500000
846:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 5000000, 500000
921:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 5500000, 500000
996:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 6000000, 500000
1072:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 6500000, 500000
1150:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 7000000, 500000
1229:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 7500000, 500000
1308:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 8000000, 500000
1386:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 8500000, 500000
1464:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 9000000, 500000
1542:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 9500000, 500000
1620:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 10000000, 500000
1697:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 10500000, 500000
1774:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 11000000, 500000
1851:-- WHERE:  1 LIMIT 11500000, 500000
```

...and the result of `grep -c 'INSERT INTO ' mybackup.sql` is **923**.

Each of those 923 insert statements is almost exactly 1MB each. Why is mysqldump producing so many insert statements for each command. I would have expected to only see 24 insert statements, but the command seems to be producing 38 inserts for each batch.

Is there something I can put in my.cnf or pass to mysqldump to stop it breaking the dump into inserts of 1MB increments?

mysql **Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44**
mysqldump **Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.44**

I re-ran the job with the additional `net_buffer_length=64M` option in the mysqldump commands. But I got `Warning: option 'net_buffer_length': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 16777216`. I took a look in `my.cnf` to see if there was anything set to 16M, and `key_buffer` and `query_cache_size` were. I set them both to 64M too and re-ran, but got the same warning.

The resulting dump file seems fine, and the insert statements are now ~16MB each. Is it possible to increase that even further? Is there an option capping the allowed buffer length?

I set the mysql `net_buffer_length` variable in `my.cnf` to 64M but, like the documentation says, it was set to it's max value which is 1048576 (1MB). But the `net_buffer_length` option to mysqldump let me bring the max insert size up to 16MB (even though it was reduced from the requested 64MB).

I'm happy enough to go along with 16MB inserts, but I'd be interested in increasing that if I can.

---

Just one last thought. It seems like I'm completely wasting my time trying to do any kind of batching myself, because mysqldump will do exactly what I want itself by default. So if I just run:

```
mysqldump -u root -p[mypassword] --net_buffer_length=16M mydb mytable > mybackup.sql
```

...for any table, no matter how large, I never have to worry about the inserts being too big because mysqldump will never create one larger than 16MB.

I don't know what else `--skip-extended-insert` could be needed for, but I can't imagine I'll have to use it again.

Comment: You mentioned "my `max_allowed_packet`" as though it were a single setting. It's two independent settings -- the server side and the client side.  Passing `--max-allowed-packet=...` a value equivalent to the server's may be the key to avoiding the coercion of net_buffer_length downward.  Or, the fact that you can set it to 16MiB may be a featurebug, since the documented limit seems to be 1MiB.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my question, but the backup will never take place across a network, always localhost. The max_allowed_packet is 64M under both the `mysqld` and `mysqldump` sections in the `my.cnf` config.

Comment: Ah, so you have that covered.  Incidentally, max_allowed_packet is a poorly-named option.  It actually refers to the size of a MySQL layer 7 "packet", not an IP packet or Ethernet frame.  The MySQL packet will be split into however many segments/packets/datagrams/frames are necessary to transport it on the network.   To add to the terminology confusion, a MySQL "packet" up to `max_allowed_packet` can be split among multiple MySQL "packets" with all but the last being exactly 0xffffff bytes long. (If not for being off-by-one, I'd be tempted to believe this plays a role in the 16MB limit).

Comment: --skip-extended-insert is very useful if you want to have it row by row. We used it for a config-table so we could diff versions. One large line is not at all useful for a diff. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump limits it's line length according to your my.ini settings, possibly on your client they are smaller than on your server. The option is `net_buffer_length`.

Often you have the problem the other way round: On the big Server this option has a big value, and when you get lines with 512 MB in a row, you can not insert into the local database or the test database.

[Option](http://muzso.hu/2013/04/19/how-to-limit-the-number-of-records-put-into-an-insert-statement-by-mysqldump)

Stolen from there:

> To check the default value of this variable, use this: mysqldump
>   --help | grep net_buffer_length
>
> For me it was almost 1 MB (i.e. 1046528) and it produced enormous
>   lines in the dump file. According to the 5.1 documentation the
>   variable can be set between 1024 and 1048576. However for any value
>   below 4096 it told me this: Warning: option 'net_buffer_length':
>   unsigned value 4095 adjusted to 4096. So probably the minimum on my
>   system was set to 4096.
>
> Dumping with this resulted in a lot more sane SQL file: mysqldump
>   --net_buffer_length=4096 --create-options --default-character-set="utf8" --host="localhost" --hex-blob --lock-tables --password --quote-names --user="myuser" "mydatabase" "mytable" > mytable.sql

Comment: Yeah, it's 1046528 for me, so that makes sense, but the option I had to search for was actually `net-buffer-length` (dashes, not underscores). So it seems that I can't defeat those 1MB increments? Because the `net_buffer_length` can't exceed 1MB?

Comment: I think you could extend that value either via --net-buffer-length=128M or in my.ini. Have you tried giving the option to mysqldump?

Comment: Just FYI, all MySQL options can be specified with either dashes or underscores.

Comment: @miken32 In my case `mysqldump --help | grep net_buffer_length` produces no output but `mysqldump --help | grep net-buffer-length` gives the requested info.  Perhaps different in help than in execution but just sayin.